# Twitter Bootstrap 4 modal box won't show in Chrome

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-modal

Well, recently spotted some weird activity: I have a Bootstrap 3 modal box, that activates via data-attributes. Here is my HTML:

```
<li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalImage" class="quickview" data-img-src="<IMG SRC by Laravel Blade>">
   <img src="<IMG SRC by Laravel Blade>" alt="<IMG ALT by Laravel Blade>">
</li>
```

And the modal box itself:

```
<!--modal-image-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalImage" role="dialog"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8)!important">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img class="modal_image" src="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript (I use it because this modal is used for opening a bigger image on click, and images are inside the image gallery (bxSlider)):

```
/* Open Modal box for larger image; */
$(".quickview").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var imgSrc = $this.data("img-src");
    $(".modal-body > img.modal_image").attr("src", imgSrc);
    $('#modalImage').modal('show');
});
```

The problem (and the weirdness) is that it works on every browser I tested, but Chrome. It even works on IE and Edge (that is based on Chromium). In Chrome nothing happens, no Console error messages, anything.

Any ideas?

P.S. And yes - my JS is wrapped with `$(document).ready`, so it executes only when page is loaded

Comment: I have checked in Chrome by using Bootstrap 4.2.1 its working fine. Clear out the cache and history and then try. Also you can check with window.onload.

Comment: @WebchipEnterprise, cleared cache and history. But this problem also persists while using Chrome Incognito mode (that disables caching as well). I've got Bootstrap 4.1.13. BTW, putting the `$('#modalImage').modal('show');` in the Chrome's console fires up the empty modal box

Answer (score 0):

It seems like latest chrome broken down modal display on Chrominium using latest version. I also have same issues as well.